# init] returning date an hour in the past?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nslog

When I call

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

in order to get the current date and time, I check it with:

```
NSLog(@"Date now: %@", now);
```

the date outputted is one hour in the past.

> 2010-10-08 12:04:38.227
>   MiniBf[1326:207] Now: 2010-10-08
>   11:04:38 GMT

Is my time zone set incorrectly somewhere perhaps?

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Are you testing with simulator or real device? Is summer time (daylight saving time) active? Please provide more information.

Comment: I'm testing it using the simulator. I can't find anywhere in the simulator to disable daylight saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter to localize the date:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]);
```

Comment: That does indeed display the correct date. However, the date when initialised as above is still wrong by an hour... :o

Comment: NSDate works in GMT "The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface. This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT."

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that behavior on the DatePicker running on iOS 4.1 devices while on iOS 4.0 and previous it does not happen. I can't confirm it is actually the same bug.

But I suggest you check whether is related with the acknowledged by Apple bug regarding dates/summer time/4.1 by running that code on < 4.1. Then you will need to decide whether to hack a fix for that particular version/dates or wait for the next release of the SDK to fix it and not support 4.1 devices...

The bug I'm talking about I believe only happens while passing dates within the summer time period (2010: 28th March - 31st October)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

I am using it and giving me perfect result.

Comment: this method uses the -init method, ie you can read it as [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease]; There should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your timezone is wrong in your iPhone simulator. Press the home button, go to settings.app and correct it ;)

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the settings to change the time. The time on the status bar is also correct.