# Can't serialize NSDate with CJJsonSerializer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, touchjson

I try to add `NSDate` to `NSMutableDictionary`, and then make it a `JSon` string with this methods:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[d setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
NSData *jsondata = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:d error:nil];
NSString *requestBody = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

And i have couple of issue:
1) The `jsondata` is nil, and then the `requestBody` is nil too.
2) The `[NSDate date]` getting me wrong date, not like the date in my iPhone:

```
2013-01-19 11:48:46 +0000
```

Any  help with this issue?

Edit:

When i print the error i got this msg:

```
Error Domain=TODO_DOMAIN Code=-1 "Cannot serialize data of type '__NSDate'" UserInfo=0x177850 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot serialize data of type '__NSDate'}
```

It's not possible to do it?

Comment: If something's going wrong, it's useful to check what the `error` parameter has been set to. You're passing `nil`; try passing reference to an `NSError *`  variable (i.e. `NSError *e = nil`, then pass `&e` to the error argument) and see what it gets set to afterwards. Regarding your second issue, it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976530/returns-a-date-an-hour-in-the-future).

Comment: I edit my post with more info.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems very unlikely that the dictionary would fail to insert the date.  It seems much more likely that the problem is with the `CJSONSerializer`.

Try the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[d setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsondata = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:d error:&error];

if (!jsonData)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@ while serialising to JSON");
}

NSString *requestBody = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

You should see an error printed to the console.

**UPDATE**

OK, so it looks like we were right, and CJSONSerializer can't serialise dates.  So you need to turn your date into a string.  This is done with NSDateFormatter.

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[d setObject:dateString forKey:@"date"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsondata = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:d error:&error];

if (!jsonData)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@ while serialising to JSON");
}

NSString *requestBody = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Hopefully you should now get the formatted date in your JSON.  You can vary the format by changing the string you pass to `stringWithDate:`.  If you're doing this a lot, you'll want a single date formatter as creating them is costly.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support dates as a standard type, so there is no automatic way to serialize an `NSDate`. You must either pass a string representation of the date, or a numeric timestamp representation. For instance, you could serialize it as a timestamp by doing something like:

```
[d setObject:@([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) forKey:@"date"]
```