# Creating NSDate from components without "timezone correction"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have a function

```
func createDate(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> NSDate {
    var comp = NSDateComponents()
    comp.day = day
    comp.month = month
    comp.year = year

    var cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    if var date = cal.dateFromComponents(comp) {
        return date
    }

    return NSDate()
}
```

If I call it with

```
createDate(07, 01, 1984)
```

the output is `1984-01-06 23:00:00 +0000`. I assume that there is some influence from the time zone. How can I adjust my code so that the output will be `1984-01-07 00:00:00 +0000`? What am I getting wrong here? How am I confused?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976530/returns-a-date-an-hour-in-the-future/4976950#4976950

Comment: As others have said, an NSDate object always contains the UTC time (or some conceptual version thereof), and that is what prints when you NSLog it.  To see the correct date/time use NSDateFormatter set to  your timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use NSDateComponents to input time. NSCalendar already has a method for you to input your date using your local time. It is called dateWithEra. 
"+0000" it is not your localTime (CET) it is UTC time. Your timeZone is not stored with your NSDate object, only the corresponding UTC date and time for your localTime input.

```
let myDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 1984, month: 1, day: 7, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!


myDate.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())!   // "Saturday, January 7, 1984 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Standard Time"


NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the log output. It will be an *unformatted* date. The actual date seems to be exactly what you intended.

If you want to *show* the exact date, you have to display it using a `NSDateFormatter`.