# IOS Swift NSDate from String output GMT midnigth

Tags: nsdate, nscalendar

I want to store in a sqlite database timeintervalSince1970.
If I use this code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
var initDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("23-03-2015 00:00")!
let timeInSeconds = initDate.timeintervalSince1970 // 1,427,324,400.0
```

When I pass timeInSeconds to NSDate:

```
let dateStore: NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSeconds)
```

If I print dateStore:

```
println(dateStore)
```

> Output '2015-03-22 23:00:00 +0000'

timeInSeconds = 1427324400.0 -> '2015-03-22 23:00:00 +0000', but to store '2015-03-23 00:00:00 +0000' the interval should be 1427328000.0

I do not know how to get it.

When I use this code:

```
let cal2: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal2.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Madrid")!

var timeZoneComps: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

timeZoneComps.day = 23
timeZoneComps.month = 3
timeZoneComps.year = 2015
timeZoneComps.hour = 0
timeZoneComps.minute = 0
timeZoneComps.second = 0

var date1: NSDate = cal2.dateFromComponents(timeZoneComps)!
println(date1)
```

> Output println: 2015-03-22 23:00:00 +0000

Any help, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28792570/2303865

Comment: Thanks Leonardo but if I use this code when I store myDate.timeIntervalSince1970 the value continue being 1427324400.0 instead of 1427328000.0 to '2015-03-26 00:00:00'

Comment: NSDate object doesn't store your timeZone, it stores a point in time (UTC) equivalent to your local time. You shouldn't use the prefix "init"  when coding in Swift.

Comment: Sorry Leonardo I don't understand well. You say that NSDate stores a point in time (UTC) equivalent to my local time. So if I understand correctly, when I store  '2015-03-26 00:00:00' in my local time is equals to '2015-03-25 23:00:00'. Is correct?

Comment: If your localTimeZone offset is 1 hour yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
let myDateMidnightLocalTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString("23-03-2015 00:00")!  // Mar 23, 2015, 12:00 AM
let timeInSeconds = myDateMidnightLocalTime.timeIntervalSince1970                // 1,427,079,600.0  
let dateStored = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSeconds)                    // Mar 23, 2015, 12:00 AM  matches
dateStored.timeIntervalSince1970                                                 // 1,427,079,600.0  matches
```

Comment: Thanks, then when you store this date in seconds is equals to 1,427,079,600.0 but in my local time is 1,427,065,200.0. In both cases when converting NSTimeInterval to NSDate the date is '23-03-2015 00:00'. Sorry for my stupidity :-(