# objective c - NSDateFormatter incorrect output

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Why does the below code output the incorrect `Date` after conversion?

```
NSString *customDate = @"23-06-1993";
NSLog(@"Custom Date: %@", customDate);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *birthDayDate = [formatter dateFromString:customDate];
NSLog(@"After Conversion: %@", birthDayDate);
```

Output:

```
Custom Date: 20-12-1993
After Conversion: 1993-12-19 16:00:00 +0000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't output the wrong date. When you log an NSDate object, the time  is always GMT.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4976950/457406

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` uses your current timezone (GMT+8) unless you explicitly set. You should set your formatter's timezone as `UTC` (in other words GMT) to format your date correctly.

```
NSLog(@"Current timezone: %@", [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]);

NSString *customDate = @"23-06-1993";
NSLog(@"Custom Date: %@", customDate);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *utcDate = [formatter dateFromString:customDate];
NSLog(@"After Conversion: %@", utcDate);
```

---

```
Custom Date: 23-06-1993
After Conversion: 1993-06-23 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Changing the timezone to UTC will change the actual date, with the side effect that the date now looks correct when printed via `[date description]`.