# date playground loses a day: SWIFT

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to play with dates, saving them as strings, then returning them to dates.  my output loses a day.  Please see below for the playground code:

```
 let date = NSDate()
 let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
 let secondDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 formatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
 let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"

 let finalDate : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
 println(finalDate)
```

here's the current output:

```
date = May 7, 2015, 9:16 AM 
dateString = "Thursday, May 7, 2015" (perfect) 
let finalDate shows: "May 7, 2015, 12:00 AM" (almost perfect except the time) 
println(finalDate) reveals : 2015-05-06 16:00:00 +0000
```

I've searched around and read that it is a time zone modification?  I'm not sure.  I'll play with it more and see if it works for my needs.  Any idea why the output would be different when println is execute vs. just the calculation?

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407599/nsdateformatter-return-wrong-date-swift/29409739

Comment: You've only lost 8 hours, not an entire day.

Comment: println doesn't take into account of the time zone, so it prints the equivalent time in GMT.

Comment: [Don't confuse the point in time (NSDate) with the representation of that point at your location (the string from the NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976530/returns-a-date-an-hour-in-the-future/4976950#4976950)