# Date picker shows a different date (1 day behined) from when picked

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a UIDatePicker that is connected to a UILabel. I want the user to pick a birthday that is more than 18 years ago (age restriction). So I have this line to set the `maximumDate` value:

```
datePicker.maximumDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -18, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

This line however causes the picker to show a 1 day behind the selected date. for example if I choose `September 27, 1956` on the picker the label shows `September 26, 1956` I believe it has to do with `NSDate()` using a different timezone one that is behind my local timezone.

```
switch dequeueFrom[indexPath.row] {
    case .Birthday:
        if let pickedBday = pickedBday,
        let bday = NSDate.dateFromISOString(pickedBday) {
            (cell as! RegisterTextFieldCell).content(bday.longFormattedString())
        }
```

`// dateFromISOSString is declared in an extension.swift`

```
class func dateFromComponents(components: NSDateComponents) -> NSDate? {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    return calendar?.dateFromComponents(components)
}

class func dateFromString(string: String) -> NSDate?  {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSS"

    if let stringDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string) {
        return stringDate
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func ISOStringFromDate() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self).stringByAppendingString("Z")
}

class func dateFromISOString(string: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    if let stringDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string) {
        return stringDate
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Any help with how I can make NSDate() be my local timezone so this one day behind issue can go away? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy what do you mean by relevant code? this is the one line that is setting the "age restriction" on the datePicker

Comment: The code where you set the label would be a great start since that is where you are having your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407599/nsdateformatter-return-wrong-date-swift/29409739

Comment: @rmaddy the label just shows the datepicker's date that's it, if I comment out the line `datePicker.maximum = NSCalendar....` the label would show the correct date.

Comment: It *is* relevant how you convert the picker's date (which is an NSDate) to the label text (which is a String).

Comment: @MartinR ahhh I see now, well I have uploaded the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your method ISOStringFromDate because you are getting the local time and manually adding the Z (Z means UTC) to the string. Try like this when creating your iso8601:

```
extension NSDate {
    var iso8601: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

and your code should be:

```
pickedDate.iso8601  // to get your date iso8601 string
```

Comment: also make sure when displaying it you don't set UTC time on your date formatter