# Convert time string into date swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am using firebase as a backend and storing a string of time like this 7:00 PM.

I am trying to convert the string received from Firebase and convert it into NSDate so I can sort it, change the time..etc

I've looked online and come up with this code so far

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
                  dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
                  let date = dateFormatter.date(from: item)
                  self.times.append(date!)
                  print("Start: \(date)")
```

where item is the string (7:00 PM)

When I run the app, the console returns:

> Item: 9:00 AM
>
> Start: Optional(2000-01-01 05:00:00 +0000)

Ive set timezone, locale, format. Why is the time being returned not correct?

A few other examples printed out:

> Item: 1:20 PM
>
> Start: Optional(2000-01-01 17:20:00 +0000)
>
> Item: 9:40 AM
>
> Start: Optional(2000-01-01 05:40:00 +0000)
>
> Item: 10:00 AM
>
> Start: Optional(2000-01-01 05:00:00 +0000)
>
> Item: 12:00 PM
>
> Start: Optional(2000-01-01 17:00:00 +0000)

Comment: For a start, the format for 12 hour am/pm time is "hh", not "HH"

Comment: That was actually a mistake, I did have it as hh:mm a (Edited the post)

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: I guess that you live in a 5 hours difference from GMT+0? Right? That explains the hour issue. For the year/month/day, it's because your string doesn't contains any information about it, so it's putting it a the reference 2000.

Comment: Yes I am. How do I fix it then? Is there anyway to have it show 9:00 AM no matter what ?

Comment: A `Date` is an absolute point in time and has no time zone. To display it as "9:00 AM" you have to convert it back to a string using a date formatter. – Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407599/nsdateformatter-return-wrong-date-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours and some more

Comment: So removing the timezone when converting to NSDate and when converting back to String will solve the problem? For example: Convert 9:00 PM (String) to 9:00 PM (Date) add 2 hours and convert back to a string will return 11:00 PM?

Comment: @MartinR hh:mm a is what I had before but the app crashes. It doesn't crash when HH:mm a

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Always remember this: `Date` / `NSDate` stores times in UTC. If your timezone is anything but UTC, the value returned by `print(date)` will always be different.

You can make it print out the hour as stored in Firebase by specifying a UTC timezone. The default is the user's (i.e. your) timezone:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let item = "7:00 PM"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: item)
print("Start: \(date)") // Start: Optional(2000-01-01 19:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use current date instead of 2000-01-01?

Comment: That's a bad idea. "Current date" changes everyday. You don't care about the date part, so it's best to choose a fixed date

Comment: That's exactly what I needed for my project. I already figured out - I have to set 'defaultDate' to make it work.