# Convert string time to date Swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I followed the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333223/convert-time-string-into-date-swift), however the year returned is always wrong, like 2000-01-01. Is there a way to simply append to Date() the time I'm passing in? So I have the time as string, this is the func:

```
// Converts String time (01:07 PM) to Date (2000-01-01 18:07:00 +0000)
    func convertStringTimeToDate(item: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: item)
        
        return date!
    }
```

For example, time: `01:07 PM` would wrongly give me `1 Jan 2000, 01:07 PM`. The year has to be correct.

Comment: add one more line
`dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`

Comment: That doesn't work @nghiahoang

Comment: ya, what is your expectation output when input = 01:07 PM ?

Comment: Today's date with that hour, so: 07/08/2020 01:07 PM (don't pay attention to format) @nghiahoang

Comment: so add one more line `dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()`

Comment: Perfect, that was what I was looking for. Now it works :) I removed the timezone tho, because everyone has a different one @nghiahoang

Comment: Upvote please haha

Comment: @nghiahoang You should post your solution as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Sir

Comment: @nghiahoang If you don't post the answer I can't upvote you because I'm new

Comment: ;) you’re welcome man

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution, thanks @nghiahoang for the help:

```
// Converts String time (01:07 PM) to Date (2000-01-01 18:07:00 +0000)
    func convertStringTimeToDate(item: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()
        
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: item)
        
        return date!
    }
```

Comment: You need to set your DateFormatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" otherwise this might crash your app if the device 24h time settings is set to 24 instead of 12